# How do I make my MySQL statement to have sub query for limit & group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join 4 tables which have `group by`, `order by` & `limit`. I got a `SQL syntax error` when I put LIMIT for pagination.

```
SELECT   ads.ad_id            ,
         ads.ad_uid           ,
         ads.ad_title         ,
         ads.ad_content       ,
         ads.ad_name          ,
         ads.ad_price         ,
         ads.ad_maincat       ,
         ads.ad_subcat        ,
         ads.ad_condition     ,
         ads.ad_quantity      ,
         ads.ad_att           ,
         ads.ad_view          ,
         ads.ad_aff           ,
         ads.ad_status        ,
         ads_images.img_id    ,
         ads_images.img_aid   ,
         ads_images.img_uid   ,
         ads_images.img_big   ,
         ads_images.img_bigx  ,
         ads_images.img_bigy  ,
         ads_images.img_thumb ,
         ads_images.img_sort  ,
         users.user_username  ,
         users.user_fullname  ,
         users.user_gravatar  ,
         users.user_id        ,
         categories.cat_id    ,
         categories.cat_parent,
         categories.cat_name  ,
         categories.cat_slug
FROM     ads
         INNER JOIN ads_images
         ON       ads.ad_id = ads_images.img_aid
         INNER JOIN users
         ON       ads.ad_uid = users.user_id
         INNER JOIN categories
         ON       ads.ad_maincat = categories.cat_parent
         AND      ads.ad_subcat  = categories.cat_id
WHERE    ads.ad_status           = 1
AND
GROUP BY ads.ad_id 
ORDER BY
ads.ad_id DESC
LIMIT {$startpoint},{$limit}
```

May I know what is the correct statement to use `LIMIT` with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the erroneous `AND` before your `GROUP`

Comment: Awwwwww eagle eye. Thanks @Umbrella